# Problems with executing a popup tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, popup

In this app I'm trying to execute a popup in which an user can write a date. This popup has to occur after the user clicks a submit button I have already created. The date the user input into this popup has to be saved into a variable which will be used later on on the code. In order to do all this I tried the following:

```
def CreateOrderPop(self):
            def popup():
                #contenido = input("Contenido de Orden ")
                #diaDeEntregar = input("Dia de Entrega")
                self.userentryA = Entry("Dia de Entrega: ")
                self.userentryA.pack()
                self.userentryAbu = Button(text= "Guardar", command = self.guardarFechaOrden)
                self.userentryAbu.pack()
            def guardarFechaOrden(self):
                global userDate
                userDate = self.userentryA.get()
                self.destroy()    

    def submit(self):
        result = next(self.counter)
        global orderResult
        orderResult = str(result)
        global contents1
        contents1 = ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get())) 
        global contents2
        contents2 = ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_email.get()))
        global contents3
        contents3 = ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_numtc.get()))
        global contents4
        contents4 = ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_addinf.get(1.0, "end")))

        def CreateOrder():
            fecha = datetime.now()
            fechaDeCreacion = fecha.strftime(" %A, %B %d, %Y" )
            #diaDeEntregar = userDate
            #global fechaDeEntrega
            #fechaDeEntrega = fechaDeCreacion + str(diaDeEntregar)
            numOrden = orderResult
            return fechaDeCreacion,  orderResult


        completeOrden = [contents1, contents2,  contents3, contents4, CreateOrder()]
        completeOrdenEnum = "Orden Num:" + orderResult, completeOrden
        Database.mainDatabase.append(completeOrdenEnum)

        command = self.CreateOrderPop()
```

After running the code and clicking the submit button, everything runs normal except I don't get the popup I want.

*CHANGES*

I added this class to help me create what I was looking for:

```
class PopOrden:
        def __init__(self,master):
            self.master = master
            top=self.top=Toplevel(master)
            self.l=Label(top,text="Fecha de Entrega")
            self.l.pack()
            self.e=Entry(top)
            self.e.pack()
            self.b=Button(top,text='Ok',command=self.cleanup)
            self.b.pack()

        def cleanup(self):
            self.value=self.e.get()
            self.top.destroy()


        def entryValue(self):
            return self.w.value
            print(self.w.value)
```

The previous code along with this edited code:

```
def submit(self):

        result = next(self.counter)
        print (result)
        def controLoo():
            if result == 1: 
                self.CreateOrderPop()
        command = controLoo()
        global orderResult
        orderResult = str(result)
        global contents1
        contents1 = ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get())) 
        global contents2
        contents2 = ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_email.get()))
        global contents3
        contents3 = ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_numtc.get()))
        global contents4
        contents4 = ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_addinf.get(1.0, "end")))

        def CreateOrder():
            fecha = datetime.now()
            fechaDeCreacion = fecha.strftime(" %A, %B %d, %Y" )
            #diaDeEntregar = PopOrden
            #global fechaDeEntrega
            #fechaDeEntrega = fechaDeCreacion + str(diaDeEntregar)
            numOrden = orderResult
            return fechaDeCreacion,  orderResult


        completeOrden = [contents1, contents2,  contents3, contents4, CreateOrder()]
        completeOrdenEnum = "Orden Num:" + orderResult, completeOrden
        Database.mainDatabase.append(completeOrdenEnum)


        command = self.database_window()


        self.clear()


        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Orden #"+ orderResult, message = "Orden Guardada")
```

However, I'm NOW having issues with a blank tk popu that's also generated with the popup I want.

Comment: your indentation appears to be all messed up .

Comment: I've decided to take another route which is working.

Comment: This is just a small snippet of my full code.

Comment: We don't need a small snippet, we need a MCVE. It forces you to remove all unrelated code. When you go through that process, often you will incover the problem yourself, and will have a better understanding as a nice side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by everything runs normal, because your code seems to have some major formatting issues (indentation to say the least). However, 'pop-ups' are usually achieved with `Toplevel()` widgets. See [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) useful resource. It is a great resource for all things tkinter in my opinion.

Also, you might find the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020885/creating-a-popup-message-box-with-an-entry-filed) question helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a message box directly

```
from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
root = Tk()

def popUp():
    result = tkinter.messageBox.popUp("Quiz","Are you ready? ")
    # result wil be yes or no
    if result == 'yes':  
        #do something
   else:
        # do something

submitButton = Button(root,text= "Submit")
submitButton.bind("<Button-1",popup) 
# onleft click on submit popup method gets called
submitButton.pack()
```