# How to get a value from a popup in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a popup with one `Entry` and one `Button`. I need to get whatever the user input into that entry and bring back to my main window. I'm using Python 3.6.0. I have the following code (which was inspired by the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020885/creating-a-popup-message-box-with-an-entry-field)):

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.server_address = None

        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Application')
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.master.minsize(width=800, height=600)
        self.master.maxsize(width=800, height=600)

        self.grid()
        self.init_menubar()

    def init_menubar(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Set remote server", command=self.call_server_config)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Set refresh delay", command=None)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)

        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help", command=None)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=helpmenu)

    def call_server_config(self):
        popup = ServerConfig(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(popup.top)
        print('DEBUG:', popup.value)
        self.create_widgets()


class ServerConfig(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="Server address")
        self.label.pack()
        self.entry = Entry(self.top)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.top, text='Ok', command=self.top.destroy())

        self.value = self.entry.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<...>\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Documents/<...>/tk-client.py", line 45, in call_server_config
    popup = ServerConfig(self)
  File "D:/Documents/<...>/tk-client.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.button = Button(self.top, text='Ok', command=self.top.destroy())
  File "C:\Users\<...>\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2363, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\<...>\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!application.!toplevel"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code caused the exception:

```
self.button = Button(self.top, text='Ok', command=self.top.destroy())
```

The reason for this is because `self.top.destroy()` was first evaluated when you created the button. Therefore you couldn’t place the button on `self.top` as it was destroyed. You will need to change it to this:

```
self.button = Button(self.top, text='Ok', command=self.top.destroy)
```

`command=self.top.destroy` which only execute `self.top.destroy` when the button get pressed

Comment: Indeed, it was this childish mistake, hahaha. Thanks!